# $Tr(A^k) = Tr(B^k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbf{C})$.
Let us consider the following assertions :

(i) $\forall k \in [[ 1,n ]]$, $\mathrm{Tr}(A^k) = \mathrm{Tr}(B^k)$

(ii) $\forall k \in \mathbf{N}$, $\mathrm{Tr}(A^k) = \mathrm{Tr}(B^k)$

(iii) $P_A = P_B$ where $P_A$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$

I want to prove (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)  $\Rightarrow$ (iii) in this order.
For the implication (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) I am looking for a proof **without using Newton's identities** (which would directly prove (i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)).

For (ii)  $\Rightarrow$ (iii) I think I have a proof.

Let $\mathrm{Sp}(A) \cup \mathrm{Sp}(B) = \{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_p\}$ with $\lambda_i$ are all different. Let $m_i$ the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ in $P_A$ and $n_i$ the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ in $P_B$. (If $\lambda_i \notin \mathrm{Sp}(A)$ then $m_i=0$.)

$(i)$ is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^p (n_i-m_i) \lambda_i^k = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbf{N}$. If we take only the $p-1$ first equations, we have a Cramer linear system because the determinant of this system is a Vandermonde determinant which is non-null. The only solution is the trivial one which implies that $n_i-m_i=0$ so $n_i=m_i$. We can conclude that $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \mathrm{Sp}(B)$ and all eigenvalues have the same multiplicity  and  therefore $P_A=P_B$.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Newton identites ? It is like they are made for this kind of problem...

Comment: Because this exercice has been given to students who are not supposed to know Newton identities.

Comment: How much complex analysis is allowed?  I think this can be done with careful manipulation of Laurent series and a degree argument.